Subscription stuck in new subscription pbi reporting services
I'm having a problem with my subscriptions, I've checked the mail server and everything seems to be fine, I've also reviewed the email extensions and I can't find the problem, I think the problem would be where the subscriptions didn't even get executed like that This has been done manually from SQL, does anyone know what could be done?
How could I solve it
